# Selected RadioButton from ListBox Contents WindowsPhone8

Tags: c#, linq, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have placed a Radio button in a listbox content and binded it with list of `QuizOption1`
binding is working fine and showing the radio button checked if the property `IsSelected` is passed as true. the class definition is given below.

```
    class QuizOption1
    {
        public int QuizID { get; set; }
        public int QuizOptionID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

While checking for the checked items, i am using following code

```
            var lstItems = (List<QuizOption1>)lst.ItemsSource;
            var selItems = lstItems.Where(op => op.IsSelected == true).FirstOrDefault();
```

The binding is as follows.

```
<ListBox  Name="lst1" Grid.Row="1" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <RadioButton 
                                    Foreground="#333333"
                                    Background="#ffededed" 
                                    Tag="{Binding QuizOptionID}"
                                    Content="{Binding Description}"
                                    IsEnabled="True"
                                    GroupName="{Binding QuizID}"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

but selItems is always null. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you're setting the binding? A full repro would be even better...

Comment: @MattLacey thanks, i have updated the question with binding.

Comment: GroupName="{Binding QuizID}"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>

Comment: plz note that if i provide IsSelected= true for any one option it gets checked for first radio in one group but still it doesn't reflect change in the same binding.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple, i need to add the `Mode=TwoWay` attribute in binding and binding looks like following.
Thanks anyways.

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: And iNotifyPropertyChanged interface implementation.